# How to suppress the 'ASCII filter option' dialog in OpenOffice?

Tags: command-line, openoffice-writer

I want to open a TXT file in OpenOffice via command line. The command is -o.

> swriter.exe -o "xyz.txt"

However, there is a problem. Instead of simply opening the document, OpenOffice shows firstly the 'ASCII filter option' dialog, and then the actual document.

How to directly load the document?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed two properties of .TXT files which might trigger this:

1) Using UNIX LF for newline instead of Windows CR-LF. (I work on a Windows machine.)

2) Saving the file in UTF8 with BOM.

I sometimes get it with plain UTF8 (no BOM) but I haven't been able to pin down the exact cause.

In general, I think OO is expecting plain ASCII text and anything it does not expect in the text file will trigger the options box.